# How to downgrade from ubuntugis-unstable to ubuntugis-stable

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntugis

I have some problems with gdal and I would like to downgrade all of my ubuntugis related libraries on Ubuntu 16.04 again to the stable libraries.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Install ppa-purge:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Purge the ubuntugis-unstable PPA:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
```

Add ubuntugis stable repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
```

Install your packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade (or sudo apt-get install gdal etc...)
```

Comment: Humm are you sure that downgrades everthing? My qgis is now 2.14 which is according to the stable releases. My GDAL is however 2.2.1 and the stable had only upgrades until 2.1.3 if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: @joaoal it should, but if not, see https://askubuntu.com/a/799040

Comment: Or uninstall and reinstall GDAL